# npm scripts not working after reinstalling packages listed in devDependecies

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, npm-scripts

I have been developing a build system for front-end devs using npm scripts and several tasks have been defined in the `scripts` section of the `package.json`. These include typical tasks such as: minifying css, code linting, generating documentation, transpiling JavaScript… etc, etc.

All the script tasks defined achieve the expected results by executing commands via the CLI, for example `$ npm run build`, `$ npm run docs`, `$ npm run watch`...

To test that the build system can be successfully reproduced after a fresh install of the required node packages I do this:

1. make a duplicate of the project directory.
2. delete the `node_modules` folder from the duplicated project directory.
3. perform a fresh install in duplicated project directory via `$ npm install`.

This, as expected, downloads the required node packages based on those listed in the `devDependencies` section of the `package.json`.

However, after running a fresh `npm install` some of the script tasks defined such as: `$ npm run watch` no longer work successfully from the duped project.

Further investigation has revealed that the no. of top-level packages listed in the 'node_modules' folder of the duplicate project directory (i.e. the one after the fresh install) is approx 30 less than the original project directory from which the tasks successfully run. The packages missing all appear to be sub dependiencies which the packages I have installed depend on.

Also, when running `$ npm list`, via the CLI, in both the original project directory and the duped project directory (i.e. the one with the fresh install) the listed packages differ.

So, I am now in a position whereby I cannot share the project directory without including the `node_modules` folder (and its content) with it. Ideally I would like to share the boilerplate code with fellow developers and they simply `cd` to the project directory and run `$ npm install` themselves.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this issue. It's not something I've encountered before.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have your version ranges specified loosely in your `package.json` (with `^`, `~`, or `*`). Your original directory contains outdated versions. When you run `npm install` in the new directory, a later (and incompatible) version is installed (with different dependencies).

To verify, go to your original directory and run `npm outdated`. This will give you a list of all the outdated dependencies, along with the current version installed, the latest version allowed by your version ranges in the `package.json`, and the latest version number of the package. Like this:

```
$ npm outdated
Package                        Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
eslint                          1.10.3  1.10.3   3.9.1  postcss-import
eslint-config-i-am-meticulous    2.0.0   2.0.0   5.0.2  postcss-import
pkg-resolve                     0.1.14  0.1.14   0.2.2  postcss-import
postcss-scss                     0.1.9   0.1.9   0.4.0  postcss-import
```

If any of the `Current` and `Wanted` version numbers differ, a fresh install in your new directory *will result in different versions being installed*.

Most npm packages use [SemVer](http://semver.org/). Unless you use a `*` for the version number in your `package.json`, you should be safe from breaking changes for the most part. However, package authors are human, and sometimes they mess up semver. There are also a few npm packages that don't follow semver. Those packages either should not be used or their version numbers should be pinned.

It may be helpful if you post the `devDependencies` section of your `package.json`.